# Android library to show wkb

Tags: openstreetmap, android, well-known-binary

I would like to use open street map to show data from wkb file(wkb + some extended attributes). I have found out that wkb file is possible to read/query using spatialite. But i dont know how to combine spartilite with map library to show data as another layer. Is any existing android library MapForge, Mapbox, osmdroid, ... suitable for this? What steps should be performed?

Answer (score 1):

You can read WKB as many other geo formats using [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm)
 and add this data onto osm map as vector overlay. As example [GeoJson Layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-android-sdk/api/geojsonlayer/) from MapBox SDK